# Does editing your own post leave details about each edit?

Tags: support, editing

Basically what the title says, Does editing your own post leave details about each edit?

Comment: Yes, but if you make a million edits within 5 minutes, they all get collapsed into one edit in the edit history.

Comment: If you tried to make a million edits within 5 minutes, I suspect there would be problems somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, unless you do more than one edit within a 5-minute window.

Edits by a user to their own post are shown in the post's revision history ([random example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/115540/revisions)).

But more than one edit by the same user to *any* post within 5 minutes, if no comments or answers are added during that 5-minute window, are all rolled into a single edit in the revision history. See also [questions with the [grace-period] tag on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grace-period) for more details about how this works. This is called **shadow-editing**, and just for fun, I've done it on this very answer here: first posting it with just the first two paragraphs, and then going back to edit in more text within a 5-minute window.

(This is useful for people who wish to be the so-called [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem): a user can post a short and minimal answer in order to be the first to answer a given question, and then edit their answer to be longer, better, and more detailed, and these changes will not show in the answer's revision history provided they're all done within 5 minutes. This strategy has often been employed by users such as DVK, <strike>Richard</strike> Valorum, Jason Baker, and myself.)

Comment: Comments break up the grace period? So if I had commented a minute ago, I would have thwarted your rewriting in the 5-minute window?

Comment: Ok, I see now. I was trying to pull up an example to show, but you did it for me.

Comment: @anaranjada Correct. And you've just thwarted my *second* shadow edit by leaving that comment there.

Comment: "*Strategy"*? You credit me with far more cunning (and sense) than reality would suggest.